# R ggplot2 X Axis Sorting Issue -- Alphabetization

Tags: r

I am trying to plot data in ggplot, but the x axis is sorting alphebetically despite my using reorder commands in the aes() field.

I've tried most of the reordering solutions suggested online (and my x axis cannot seem to be made into a factor because data is melted), and none are seeming to work.

(dff is a melted data frame)

```r
ggplot(dff, aes(x = fct_reorder(dff$odname, dff$stop_sequence), y = dff$value, color = variable, group = variable)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = fct_reorder(dff$odname, dff$stop_sequence))) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5,10.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1)) + 
  labs(color="Comparisons\n") +
  xlab("Station Pair") +
  ylab("Time (mins)") + 
  ggtitle(paste("Schedule adherence on", target_route, "in date range", datemin,"-",datemax))
```

What I have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWWy6.png

What I want:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxT3T.png

code for the working one (and yes I did try using reorder() in the broken example:

```r
ggplot(dfTotal, aes(x = reorder(dfTotal$odname, stop_sequence), y = dfTotal$value, color = variable, group = variable)) + 
  geom_line(lwd =.75) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.5,1.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1)) + 
  labs(color="Time Comparisons\n") +
  xlab("Station Pair") +
  ylab("Peak/Midday") +
  ggtitle(paste("Peak/midday runtime ratios on", ROUTES, "in date range", datemin,"-",datemax))
```

What is wrong? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is it resolved by using `x = fct_reorder(odname, stop_sequence)`?

Comment: Also, `dff$value` should be just `value`, otherwise you can get unexpected results.